# Event System with Template class deriving from Non-Template base class in c++

Tags: c++, templates

### What I'm doing

I'm working on an event system. Basically there are "slots" which any member can chime into. All they need is an event name which it will be listening to, and a function. Since all the slots are stored I had to store them as a variable in a class.

### The Problem

The function becomes unavailable when it's placed into the SlotBase class. I am wondering if there is a way to retain the function in the Slot class while storing in in the SlotBase class.

### The Code

```
class SlotBase { };
//              TC - Template Class
//                              TA - Template Arguments (types)
template <class TC, typename ...TA>
class Slot : public SlotBase  {
public:
    Slot(TC* funcClass, void(TC::*func)(TA...)) {
        SetSlot(funcClass, func);
    }
    template <int ...Is>
    void SetSlot(TC* funcClass, void(TC::*func)(TA...), int_sequence<Is...>) {
        function = std::bind(func, funcClass, placeholder_temp<Is>{}...);
    }
    void SetSlot(TC* funcClass, void(TC::*func)(TA...)) {
        SetSlot(funcClass, func, make_int_sequence<sizeof...(TA)>{});
    }
    std::function<void(TA...)> returnFunction(){
        return function;
    }
private:
    std::function<void(TA...)> function;
};


//...


class RandomClass {
public:
    void randomFunction(int a, float b, int c){ //do stuff };
}


//...


RandomClass randC;
SlotBase baseS;

Slot newSlot(&randC, &RandomClass::randomFunction);
baseS = newSlot;


//...
//Later on down the line when an event was found matching slot call slot function


baseS.returnFunction()(//Correct arguments go here - leaving this out (a lot more code));
```

I didn't include the code for the integer sequences in the 'std::bind' as it isn't related to the problem.

### What I have tried

I know that if I use a Slot cast on the `baseS` variable that would give me the result but I am unable to do so because I don't know the templates that Slot will have.

I have seen many similar posts stating to make `baseS` a pointer (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569073/c-stdmap-of-template-class-values)) but I still don't understand how you would grab the function.

Comment: What does `retain the function in the Slot class while storing in in the SlotBase class.` mean?  How would you store it without knowing its type?  Do you mean you want to store a bound function taking no arguments (i.e. all arguments are bound)?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yes, all I need to store is the functions, the arguments which will be sent will come in later. I need to be able to call the function later (that's what I mean by retain). Right now, the function is being sliced so I can't access it. If I make `SlotBase` a pointer it won't be sliced but I still wont be able to access it. I can't write a function in the base class returning the function because it doesn't know the types. The only reason I have the base class (SlotBase) is to be able to store the template class (Slot).

Comment: How about making a pure virtual function in SlotBase which retrieves the function?  You'd then implement it in the derived (template) class.

Comment: @JohnZwinck That was my first thought but don't I have to define the return type in the SlotBase class?

Comment: Yes, the return type could be a function taking no arguments, i.e. the completely bound function.  If you need to return multiple different types, well, I guess you can create another class hierarchy with a base class which you can return, but I don't know what the point is.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Well TA is the template arguments. The idea is to allow any random function with any number of arguments to be stored. All it does is store the types on the function (TA). Then all this information is saved under the type std::function<void(TA...)> so I don't know how many arguments there are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69163/discussion-between-trevorpeyton-and-john-zwinck).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start to accept that at some point if you want to use polymorph objects, you will need to create a virtual function in `SlotBase`. If you want to cast back to your type at creation before using the function, the polymorphism makes no sense, because you have carried the original type somewhere along with you to be able to do so, so why upcast anyway in the first time ?

If you really need to upcast, then you need to think about a RUNTIME solution to get back to access the derived functionality. In this case, this would mean you need to create a generic interface to your signals, so try to make a pure virtual method in `SlotBase` that will pack an undefined number of arguments, and implement that generic caller in your `Slot` so that it unpacks the arguments in order and calls your slot with the arguments. I don't know if variadic methods can be overriden though, that seems dubious. Otherwise you'll have to use boost::any or something to pack the arguments in a runtime collection.